# Post-Installation Checklist for Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, configuration, installation

I'm curious to know what folks standard post-installation checklist looks like for Windows Server 2008. I'm creating a virtual instance of 2k8 to use a base for other VMs in our test environment, so I want a clean, generic image to start them off with.

For example, the first thing I do is create C:\Utils, add it to the path, and put process explorer in there.

I'll also disable IPv6 on the NICs.

What other things to you do on all your servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Static IP
- DNS Entry
- Windows Updates (GP to WSUS server)
- Enable Remote Desktop on non-standard port
- Enable Firewall Rules (allow file sharing, rmeote desktop, etc)
- Install AV
- Join domain, move to correct OU & add in a description into AD U&C
- Install backup software
- Add server into monitoring software
- BGInfo
- Add to inventory spreadsheet

Comment: I'd say that applies to any server... substituting MS technology for the appropriate term on the appropriate stack ;)

Comment: Sorry for coming back to this so late, but thanks.